# Can't remove default app for an action in any way

Tags: settings, default-applications

The title is my problem. When I clicked on a song download link on the internet (mp3 file), it asked me whether to download or to play it. I clicked on "play" and "remember", which was the biggest fault in my whole life, as now I can't download any song at all.
I tried the following:

- Go to Settings>Apps>Music and the clear default actions button was grayed out.
- Go to Settings>Default Actions. Music app wasn't there.
- Go to Settings>Default Actions>Clear all default actions. Didn't help
- Go to Settings>Apps>Clear all app settings. That kinda hurt me as all apps lost data but obviously I still couldn't download songs
- Phone restart at least 3 times - nothing
- Software update and then all the above AGAIN, still nothing.

I just hope I don't have to reset to factory but I guess that wouldn't work either so I won't try. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: sorry, but i didn't get your point. to me it seems that you tried and played (started) the mp3 files in your browser( or may be search). the browser (say chrome) then opened your default mp3 player and played he song. now it is repeating the same.so have you tried cleaning the browser setting and resetting the browser?

Comment: Add this as an answer pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you tried and played (started) the MP3 files in your browser (or may be search). The browser (say Google Chrome) then opened your default MP3 player and played the song. Now it is repeating the same. So, try cleaning the browser setting and resetting the browser.

Comment: Thanks! That worked out, even tho it's kinda weird, since I did the clear all app preferences thing, and it even asked me if it should go on android simple mode lol. Anyway, thanks!